# How to use Fiddler 2 to compose a request?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am using asp.net web api and I want to try to see if my method work. The way I see people do this alot is through fiddler. I am trying to do this myself but I can't get it to work.

I go to the composer tab and do this.

[image]

```
public IQueryable<FoodLogRecord> Get(string email)
{
    return null;
}
```

but I get a 404 back. I also put a break point in the method and it never goes in.

Comment: I assume that `foodlog` is the controller - if your routing is `api/{controller}/{email}` go for `api/foodlog/c`, if it's `api/{controller}` only use `api/foodlog?email=c`

Comment: In case you're wondering, the request body background is RED because your request method (GET) does not normally accept a body. If you change to a POST, the background goes back to white.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the URL

```
http://localhost:50570/api/foodlog?email=c
```

Remove the Content-Length and the text from the request body.  You can't send a body with a GET request.

Comment: Oh. Did not know that. Now it is working. I tried using "post" but got the same problem. I will try "post" again.

Comment: I also seem to be having problems when I put email into a ViewModel so my Get is like Get(Test e){} and Test has a property called "Email"

Comment: @chobo2 It's an either or. You can either put the email=c in the query string and do GET, or you can put it in the body and do POST. You should use GET if it is a read-only request.

Comment: I figured out the problems. I am actually able to use what I did in my screen shot(even for get). It is just I had ";" behind it and it did not like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following URL with the code changes below: `http://localhost:50570/api/foodlog/c`

```
public IQueryable<FoodLogRecord> Get([FromUri] string email)
{
    return null;
}
```